# How can i put a skybox on a new layer with a new camera and then move the skybox?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to create a moving start effect. For example the space station is moving around the star or moving to the star. But instead moving the space station i think it will be better to make effect of the skybox moving.

I have in the Hierarchy a RigiBbodyFPSController and a child MainCamera.
Now i added a new Camera to the Hierarchy.

Now how do i make the rest  ? Moving the new camera and the skybox to new layer and move the skybox ? Or it's more logic to say to move the new camera that the skybox is with in it in the new layer.

Not sure if my idea is logic or if there are a better ways to do it.
The general idea is to make movement effect like the space station is moving around the star or to the star. Star i mean the skybox.

[image: Hierarchy]

The skybox is on the right.
I can't see the skybox in the scene view i see it only when running the game in the game view.

This is a screenshot when the game is running then i can see the skybox in scene view and game view:

[image: Hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate or move your skybox which can be possible 
by calling renderSettings

```
    RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat ("_Rotation", Time.time *speed );
```

or if you want to change your skybox each time interval use insideout shader which you can get it

https://github.com/maazirfan/InsideOut-Shader-Unity

and link it with sphere using material, add your skybox texture in it. and change that sphere by each interval,scale it as much that your rest of models will fit in and look like skybox.that might help you in your project